# Pad a column of strings in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas dataframe with string in a column like this

```
 id   b
  1   this is string1
  1   this is string2
  1   this is string3
  1   this is string4
```

Now I want to remove the first character(t) from each cell of column b. I also need to add a character `s` at the beginning and end of this column. So the output should look like this

```
 id   b
  1   shis is string1s
  1   shis is string2s
  1   shis is string3s
  1   shis is string4s
```

I know I can iterate over each row and do these operations but I was hopping there might be some efficient way of doing this. Maybe I can apply same operation on all cells of column b at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more concise/flexible approach with `df.apply`:

```
df.b = df.b.str[1:].apply('s{}s'.format)
print(df)

   id                 b
0   1  shis is string1s
1   1  shis is string2s
2   1  shis is string3s
3   1  shis is string4s
```

---

And, to replace just the first occurrence of `t`, use `pd.Series.str.replace`:

```
df.b = df.b.str.replace('t', '', 1).apply('s{}s'.format)
print(df)

   id                 b
0   1  shis is string1s
1   1  shis is string2s
2   1  shis is string3s
3   1  shis is string4s
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you tell me what `s{}s` means?

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk Will surround whatever is passed to `.format` with `s`. Example: `'s{}s'.format('lol')` --> output is `slols`

Answer (score 3):

```
In [6]: df.b = 's' + df.b.str[1:] + 's'

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   id                 b
0   1  shis is string1s
1   1  shis is string2s
2   1  shis is string3s
3   1  shis is string4s
```

if you want to replace a first occurance of `t`:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   id              b
0   1           test
1   2         a test
2   3  no occurences

In [15]: df.b = df.b.str.replace('t', '-', n=1)

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   id              b
0   1           -est
1   2         a -est
2   3  no occurences
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first and last character like this:

```
df['b'] = df.b.str.replace('^.|$', 's')
```